# Back button on navigation bar triggers an action?

Tags: iphone, navigation

Is it possible that when I hit the back button on the navigation bar and after go back to the previous page and then trigger an action on the previous page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method of viewWillAppear.